# Using Swift, how can I tell the difference between a boolean and integer value when loading data from a plist?

Tags: ios, swift, int, boolean, plist

My app needs to be able to read a plist file and know the type of data, so I created a function to figure the type of an object:

```
func getTypeOfObject(object: AnyObject) -> String {
    if object as? [String:AnyObject] != nil {
        return "dict"
    } else if object as? [AnyObject] != nil {
        return "array"
    } else if object as? Bool != nil {
        return "bool"
    } else if object as? Int != nil {
        return "int"
    } else if object as? String != nil {
        return "string"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I call the function on a number I get "bool" returned.
If I change the function to check for a number first I get "int" returned when I pass a boolean.

This seems to be because when I create a dict from data in the plist file booleans are given an integer value (1 for true and 0 for false).

Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and decided to use `CFPropertyList`, which solves my problem as booleans are `CFBooleanRef`s, not `NSNumber`s.

If anyone wants the actual code ask in the comments. It's a bit messy right now which is why I am not posting it right away.

Answer (score 4):

You can't - unless you want to parse the plist XML yourself.  The value returned will be NSNumber and it's up to you to decide if you want to treat it as a bool (via NSNumber's boolValue).

Comment: Do you know of any frameworks / libraries for parsing plist XML that I can use?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use SWXMLHash or AEXML to parse a plist file and generate a Swift dictionary. Any tips?